# How To Check If Two BufferedImages Are Equal Ignoring Color White?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have one `BufferedImage image1` and `BufferedImage image2`, and I want to know if they are equal.

`image1` is made before-hand and stored into an image file, where I convert using `ImageIO`. However, `image2` is made on the spot, so it is pretty much guaranteed that they have different sizes. What I do know is that `image2` will equal one of 9 different `image1`'s.

So, what I want to do is check if they are the same image's, but ignoring all the white pixels on the edge because they are different size, so if I compare all the pixels they would be different no matter what. If you're wondering why there is the color white on the edge, the images are numbers so the remaining space will be white.

If you want to make it simpler, the color of the real image will always be black, but I would like it better if you make it a generic solution (meaning taking in account all colors) so I could use the concepts later.

```
private boolean equals(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2) {
    // This is what I want to fill out.
}
```

What I first tried to do was to find the first non-white pixel of `image1`, and the first non-whiten pixel of `image2`, and then check the rows after that to see if everthing is equal. However, the images are pretty big, and this approach takes more than O(n ^ 2). I need a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I first tried to do was to find the first non-white pixel of image1, and the first non-whiten pixel of image2, and then check the rows after that to see if everthing is equal. However, the images are pretty big, and this approach takes more than O(n ^ 2). I need a faster way.

Most probably there is no very faster way using this approach. You can use edge detection, but the algorithms for that aren't really faster too.

I would try to work with bounding boxes for each image (number).

If it is possible to save image1 the size the number is, this were the way to go. Just shrink the image to the real size of the number and save that image to disk. You then can shrink image2 to its bounding box too and the comparison is quite simple and fast.

If shrinking is no option, calculation of the bounding box is an option. Go through the image array and detect the top most and the left most pixel in both images. You then get at least the bounding edges for the top and left side, which is all you need to compare the images. (If images can differ in size, you need the whole bounding box)

By the way, you don't need to run in O(n^2). If you detect the top most or left most pixel in both images, you can set an offset to work from. You only need to find a difference to state that these numbers are different. You can work with logic to determine, which number it must be based on simple tests. For example take numbers one (1) and zero (0). Whereas zero has white pixels in the middle part, the one must have black pixels there and vice versa. So detecting areas where the numbers definitely are black or white can help you estimate the number in the image by testing up to 9 areas.